# JS Intercept, modify and save assignment of atributes

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to log, and modify the values assigned at the innerHTML attribute of all dynamically loaded scripts-tags in the page.

To do this, I have come up with the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, "innerHTML", {
    set: function (value) {
        console.log(value + 1)
    }
});
```

When loaded into the page the following instructions:

```
o = document.createElement('script');
o.innerHTML = 1;
```

will print '2', therefore, I can 'intercept' and modify the assignments successfully.

However, I don't know to save the result into the original innerHTML variable defined in the parent prototype: `HTMLElement` so that the body of the script will actually contain show `2` when inspected through the DOM.

I have tried:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, "innerHTML", {
    set: function (value) {
        HTMLElement.prototype.innerHTML = value +1;
    }
});
```

But this results in an "illegal invocation" error.

While this:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, "innerHTML", {
    set: function (value) {
        HTMLScriptElement.prototype.innerHTML = value +1;
    }
});
```

results in: "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

How can I assign the modified value to the innerHTML attribute of the parent prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found a solution:

```
const originalInnerHTMLDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML');

// Step 2: Define custom setter.
Object.defineProperty(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
    // Define the setter
    set: function(value) {
        const modifiedValue = value + 1;

        // Call the original setter.
        originalInnerHTMLDescriptor.set.call(this, modifiedValue);
    },

    get: function() {
        return originalInnerHTMLDescriptor.get.call(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here,
`innerHTML` setter and getter belongs to `Element.prototype`
`HTMLScriptElement.prototype` inherits those accessors but does not own them.

The approach you tried to still keep the `innerHTML` functionality
does not work because you are changing the prototype of the class
instead of changing the instance `innerHTML`.

To do that, you need first to save the original `innerHTML` setter function

```js
const innerHTMLSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML').set

Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
  set(value) {
    if (this instanceof HTMLScriptElement) {
      console.log(value + 1)
      innerHTMLSetter.call(this, value + 1)
      return
    }

   innerHTMLSetter.call(this, value)
  }
})
```